# Save data every 5 minutes with python

Tags: python, json, debian, urllib2

At the time I'm just doing a `python myprogra.py &` and let this program do its thing:

```
import urllib2
import threading
import json

url = 'https://something.com'
a = []

def refresh():

    # refresh in 5 minutes
    threading.Timer(300.0, refresh).start()

    # open url
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(1000)
    except:
        return 0

    # decode json
    q = data.decode('utf-8')
    q = json.loads(q)

    # store in a
    a.append(q['ticker'])

    if len(a) > 288:
        a.pop()

    truc = json.dumps(a)

    f = open('ticker.json', 'w')
    f.write(truc)
    f.close()


refresh()
```

I have two questions:

- how comes it work since I didn't write `global a` at the start of the function
- should I use a cron for this kind of thing instead of what I'm doing? (I'm using a debian server)

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with accessing the variable `a` the way you do, because you never assign to it within the `refresh` function. It is accessed the very same way as the `url` variable or even the `json` import is accessed. If you were to assign to `a` (rather than calling a method such as `append` on it), then you would create a local variable shadowing the global a. The `global` keyword avoids the creation of a local variable for assignments.

It is up to you whether you use a program that sleeps or cron, but here are some things to keep in mind:

- Your program keeps state across requests in the variable `a`. If you were to use cron and invoke your program multiple times, you would need to store this state somewhere else.
- If your program crashes (e.g. invalid data is returned and json decoding fails with an exception), cron would start it again, so it would eventually recover. This may or may not be desired.
- When run via cron, you lower the memory footprint of the system at the expense of more computation (Python interpreter being initialized every five minutes).

Comment: +1. Note: `Timer()` also starts it in 5 minutes whether the function succeeds or not.